# How do i create instance-able objects inside of static objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know I can make static objects inside of static objects, for example:

```
aaa: {
    bbb: {}
    ccc: {}
}
```

But I want to make objects that I can have instantiated, like that:

```
aaa: {
    bbb = function(yyy): {
        this.variable // this one will be belong to aaa(parent object) instead of an instance of bbb
    }
    ccc = function(ooo) {
    }
}
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think it is "logically" useful.. Do bbb and ccc share something? isn't that easier to make a class for them and declare two objects as bbb and ccc? Also, it will be slightly more maintenable.

Comment: See if the code in my answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Statics by definition don't have a 'this' reference as this would be addressing a particular instance. Essentially you can achieve what you're trying to do like this:

```
aaa:
{
    bbb: (function() 
    {
        aaa.variable = 'something';
    })(),

    ccc:
    {

    }
}
```

note that the value of bbb here is the return value of the (self executing) function (null). Seems a bit of an odd way of doing things though, would suggest reorgainising if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. However, the "this" inside "bbb" will only refer to bbb object only. if you want to refer to aaa, since aaa is a static object, you could use aaa.x notation.

```
var aaa = {
    bbb: function(x) {
        this.x = x;
        aaa.x = x;
    },
    ccc: function(y) {
        this.y = y;
    }, 
    x: 10,
    y: 20
};

console.log(aaa.x);       // 10
var newB = new aaa.bbb(50);
console.log(newB.x);      // 50
console.log(aaa.x);       // 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution that solved it was using the "new Object" thingy.

```
all:
{
    Aaa:
    {
       create: function(yyy)
       {
           aaa = new Object();
           aaa.variable = value;
           return aaa;
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks all for trying to help :)